# Python: Extract digits from strings and find the maximum for a group

Tags: python, pandas, string, group-by

I have a table where one column is the ID and the second is the unit number. I need group by **ID** to extract max floor or max stories in that ID and create an extra column max_floor so that all rows for that ID have the same value of max_floor.

Case 1:
As per the unit number, it can start with 1 digit followed by letters or 2 digits followed by letters. In that case, extract digits and find the maximum number to get the floors, as shown in the table below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4A8s.png)

Case 2:
The unit number starts with 1 or 2 letters, followed by numbers. In that case, the number of unique values of
those letters give us the maximum number of stories,as given in the table:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJumS.png)

**First I need to filter out these cases and then calculate the floors. Need help with both**

Update: I'm trying filtering using regex for case 1. This is my code:

````
if re.search(r'^[0-9]{1,2}[A-Z]+$',df.number.fillna('').astype(str)):
   print(df.number)```

But I'm getting the error: 
```TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object```
````

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`) ...
[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)...[Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) ... [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Comment: `I need to...` - which part are you having trouble with?

Comment: This is a specific use case, but I think you will be able to sort it out yourself if you search for regex string extract and for "loc" of pandas dataframe. Basically, I would use regex to extract the relevant  digits or string, then use loc to filter it as needed.

Comment: @wwii both parts

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html

Comment: @born_naked can you help with the regex?

Comment: Using re.match, you could use this pattern to get both `(?:\d{1,2}(?=[A-Z]+$)|[A-Z]{1,2}(?=\d+))` https://regex101.com/r/iDxXpN/1 or use them separately like this to get only digits for example `\d{1,2}(?=[A-Z]+$)` https://regex101.com/r/lDl5Uk/1

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet defines a function that returns the all the digits found in the input string. As long as you don't input stings that don't have digits it should work, and problems with that can be mitigated using a simple try/except statement.

```
import re
def extract_digits(input_string):
    return re.findall('\d{1,2}')[0]
```

The code uses python's regex module to look for exactly 1 or 2 digits in the string.
Since the `findall()` function returns a list, the code accesses the first index because based on the input we expect, the first index of the returned list should always be the matched digits.